# UserForm to VLookup and display data

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

'Entry = MAC address entered and MAC should display the same MAC found in my worksheet
'Error 424: Object required

```
Private Sub MAC_Search_Click()

MAC = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Entry, MAC_Database.Range("A4:M3573"), 2, False)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is complaining about `MAC_Database` which is neither **Dim**'ed nor **Set.**

You have similar problems with `MAC` and `Entry.`  Once these problems have been corrected, you will need at least a `MsgBox` to display the value of `MAC`

Comment: Entry displays what i entered in the userform and MAC = ""